# In app purchase not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

i set my in app purchase creating two bundle id's .i created a test account and checked my in app purchase..it was working perfectly fine...after a week later when i tested i m getting this error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:` and its not returning the products...could u guys help me out.what possibly could be wrong with this

```
 -(void)Declarations
 {
if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {

    NSLog(@"parental functions are disabled");
    SKProductsRequest *productRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"com.techzone.9xo.onedollar",@"com.techzone.9xo.twodollar",nil]];
    productRequest.delegate=self;
    [productRequest start];
}else {
    NSLog(@"parental functions are enabled");
}

}
   -(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:  (SKProductsResponse *)response
{
SKProduct *validProduct=nil;
int count = [response.products count];
NSLog(@"number of prouducts present:%d",count);

if(_HintValue)
{
    validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];

}
if (!_HintValue) {
    validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:1];
}
NSLog(@"the product is :%@",validProduct.localizedTitle);
SKPayment *skpayment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:validProduct];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:skpayment];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]addTransactionObserver:self];

 }
  - (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error  
  {  
  NSLog(@"Failed to connect with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]); 

 }
 -(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {

    switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
            NSLog(@"stuff is getting purchased");
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:   
            NSLog(@"purchased properly");
            NSInteger currentValue=[Util getIntegerValueForKey:@"hintValue"];
            if(_HintValue)
            [Util setIntegerValue:10+currentValue forKey:@"hintValue"];
            if (!_HintValue) 
            [Util setIntegerValue:25+currentValue forKey:@"hintValue"];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                NSLog(@"error happened");
            }
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting an empty list of valid product IDs. You are accessing `objectAtIndex:0` of an empty array which creates that error.

if you check `response.invalidProductIdentifiers` you will find your product IDs there.

Unfortunately that can have many reasons. Have a look at this [checklist of reasons](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/) that can lead to invalid product IDs.

Comment: the thing is it was working fine the previous week but today its not...any idea...i havent published the app yet..and i m testing it using test account

Comment: I had the same problem. It seems that sometimes the sandboxed AppStore (that is used for testing) is down. But usually not longer than a couple of hours. If your problem continues, you should have a look at the checklist, although if it was was working before and you really have not changed anything, my guess would be that the sandbox is down.

Comment: Still it would not hurt if you delete the app from your device and clean your project. If you have not done that yet.

Comment: For how long does this problem occur? Longer than a day?

Comment: Then unfortunately I am out of ideas for a solution. Have a look at the checklist, maybe you find something there.